# Where is the privacy filters located in report templates?

Tags: civireport, reports, privacy

By default all privacy filters i.e. do not email, do not mail, etc is loaded in the report, except for **do not trade.**

Where in the report (contribution details )template this filters are located? How can I find out? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's at the below link and yes it's strangely missing. Do you want to open a lab ticket?

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/33307b5a0da280c63ed0d8fa1f8a3e899a217ad0/CRM/Report/Form.php#L5473

Comment: Thanks. Will open a ticket.

Comment: Had to add all the places to enable the filter in the report.